# How to use sed/awk commands to cut a string and append to the succeeding lines?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

Need your help in fixing one issue which I am facing while writing a shell script.

In a text file, I have the content as below :

Deployment '**wonderful**'

mon_z1/0 (c99-2230-333)  running

mon_z1/1 (24a90-00d)  running

mon_z1/2 (4b2-86a5fb2)  running

Deployment '**rainbow**'

post_m (333-33-22sd)  running

post_s (8-333-33d)  running

===================================

I am looking for an output something like this - where deployment name should append to the running states :
Example :

**wonderful** : mon_z1/0 (c99-2230-333)  running

**wonderful** : mon_z1/1 (24a90-00d)  running

**wonderful** : mon_z1/2 (4b2-86a5fb2)  running

**rainbow** : post_m (333-33-22sd)  running

**rainbow** : post_s (8-333-33d)  running

Please help how I can achieve with sed or awk commands

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research efforts into the question, even if it is not successful

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236678/prepend-lines-with-file-prefix-using-sed-or-awk

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/Deployment/{ gsub("\047","",$2); d=$2; next }$3~/running/{ print d,":",$0 }' file
```

The output:

```
wonderful : mon_z1/0 (c99-2230-333) running
wonderful : mon_z1/1 (24a90-00d) running
wonderful : mon_z1/2 (4b2-86a5fb2) running
rainbow : post_m (333-33-22sd) running
rainbow : post_s (8-333-33d) running
```

---

- `/Deployment/{...}` - perform an action on encountering *Deployment* line
- `gsub("\047","",$2)` - remove single quotes from *Deployment* name
- `d=$2` - capture *Deployment* name
- `$3~/running/` - on encountering line with *running* state - print the line with related *Deployment* name

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\047"}/^Deployment/{ x = $2; next }$0 != ""{ print x, ":" ,$0 }' file
```

Output:

```
wonderful : mon_z1/0 (c99-2230-333) running
wonderful : mon_z1/1 (24a90-00d) running
wonderful : mon_z1/2 (4b2-86a5fb2) running
rainbow : post_m (333-33-22sd) running
rainbow : post_s (8-333-33d) running
```

It is similar to the one from RomanPerekhrest. The difference is that I'am filtering out empty strings with:

```
$0 != ""
```

That takes care that the action is only performed on lines that are not empty.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for sed or awk, but I'm going to provide an example in perl which is easily translated to awk. The trick is how you access the match (the name of the deployment). You can use a technique like RomanPerekhrest and remove the ' marks from the 2nd field, or you can use regular expression matching and take the deployment name from the match group. This is what I did, because it's very simple in perl. As a command line:

```
cat data | perl -e "use warnings; use strict; my \$deployment; while (<>) { if (\$_ =~ /^Deployment '(.*)'/) { \$deployment = \$1; } else { print(\"\$deployment: \$_\n\"); } }"
```

Or, rewritten for clarity:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $deployment;

while (<>) {
    if ($_ =~ /^Deployment '(.*)'/) {
        $deployment = $1;
    } else {
        print("$deployment: $_\n");
    }
}
```

But do note that when you rewrite this in awk, you don't need the `while` loop. Awk's main strength is that it implicitly loops over each line and splits it into fields.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs :)